# Does there have any catia settings or VBScript to refuse catia to open files from a particular drive?

Tags: vba, catia

Catia must open/load all files from one drive only, if it is from another drive Catia must refuse to open or pop up some error.

Does there have any catia settings or VBScript to refuse catia to open files from a particular drive?

I don't have any idea to do this, Is that possible first?
Or suggest some other ideas or ways to do that

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this by defining Dlnames and allow access only to Dlnames folders (see also http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/bascugen_C2/bascudocument0000.htm )

Comment: Hi @Shrotter, thank you I have checked  this, and it was working fine on the  particular folder we gave on DLnames, But I want to access all files from the particular drive only which means access to all files, subfolders